# Why onConfigurationChanged doesn't detect screen rotation?

Tags: android, screen

I'm trying to use `onConfigurationChanged` to detect screen rotation.

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen is rotated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("ROTATEAPP", "Screen is rotated...");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ScreenRotate"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I rotated the device (Pixel 3 running Android 12) a few times, and didn't see any Toast or log entry. What's wrong here?